# Removing outliers easily in R

Tags: r, standard-deviation

I have data with discrete x-values, such as

```
x = c(3,8,13,8,13,3,3,8,13,8,3,8,8,13,8,13,8,3,3,8,13,8,13,3,3)
y = c(4,5,4,6,7,20,1,4,6,2,6,8,2,6,7,3,2,5,7,3,2,5,7,3,2);
```

How can I generate a new dataset of x and y values where I eliminate pairs of values where the y-value is 2 standard deviations above the mean for that bin. For example, in the x=3 bin, 20 is more than 2 SDs above the mean, so that data point should be removed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for me you want something like :

```
 by(dat,dat$x, function(z) z$y[z$y < 2*sd(z$y)])
dat$x: 3
[1] 4 1 6 5 7 3 2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
dat$x: 8
[1] 4 2 2 2 3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
dat$x: 13
[1] 3 2
```

**EDIT** after comment :

```
 by(dat,dat$x, 
           function(z) z$y[abs(z$y-mean(z$y))< 2*sd(z$y)])
```

**EDIT**

I slightly change the `by` function to get x and y, then I call `rbind` using `do.call`

```
   do.call(rbind,by(dat,dat$x,function(z) {
                              idx <- abs(z$y-mean(z$y))< 2*sd(z$y)
                              z[idx,]
            }))
```

or using `plyr` in single call

```
 ddply(dat,.(x),function(z) {
                 idx <- abs(z$y-mean(z$y))< 2*sd(z$y)
                  z[idx,]})
```

Comment: should that be `z$y < mean(z$y) + 2*sd(z$y)` ? when OP mentioned "the y-value is 2 standard deviations above the mean for that bin"

Comment: @liuminzhao I update my answer. I think my mistake comes from the question formulation ( i need to improve my English:))

Comment: After the edit, it gives the same result as James' `tapply`-based James' solution

Comment: And then how can I get this back into an x and y structure? (list of x and y values)

Comment: @agstudy Does the `plyr` solution remove observations above 2 SD only? Or 2 SD above AND below?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
newdata <- cbind(x,y)[-which(y>2*sd(y)), ]
```

Or you mean something like this?

```
Data <- cbind(x,y)
Data[-which(sd(y)>rowMeans(Data)), ]
```

Comment: This solution does not remove outliers in `y` by bin (*i.e.* separately for each value of `x`), but rather on a global scale

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tapply` for this, but you will lose your original ordering.

```
tapply(y,x,function(z) z[abs(z-mean(z))<2*sd(z)])
$`3`
[1] 4 1 6 5 7 3 2

$`8`
 [1] 5 6 4 2 8 2 7 2 3 5

$`13`
[1] 4 7 6 6 3 2 7
```

Comment: Then how can I restructure this into a list of x and y values?